# How to add button next to search bar when selected in SwiftUI (or UIKit if it's not possible in SwiftUI)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

How can I add a button next to the searchbar when it is currently selected in SwiftUI? An example of what I am talking about is below:

[image]

This is the code I have currently:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello")
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .navigationTitle("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

If this is not possible to do in SwiftUI, is there a way I can accomplish this by utilizing UIKit in my SwiftUI view?

Comment: You would have to make your own

Comment: @loremipsum How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this very easily with @FocusState. here is complete code, you can change it according to your requirements.

[image]

```
struct CustomSearchBar: View {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    @State private var isEditing = false
    @FocusState private var isSearchFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
    
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding([.leading])
            
            TextField("Search ...", text: $text)
                .padding([.trailing,. top, .bottom],7)
            
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(isEditing ? 1 : 0.7)
                .focused($isSearchFocused)
            
            
            if isSearchFocused {
                Button(action: {
//                    do you option event
                }) {
                    Image("option")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                }
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            }
            
            Button(action: {
//                do you cancle event
                isSearchFocused = false
            }) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }
            .padding(.trailing, 10)
            .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            
        }
        .padding()
        .background(.gray.opacity(0.3))
        .onChange(of: isSearchFocused) { newValue in
            text = ""
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but it isn't really what I'm looking for. I want to use the native `.searchable()` method. If you take a look at the Files app, and tap on the search bar, that should give you a good idea of what I'm trying to achieve.